# Sampling for model validation against a full dataset

Tags: sampling, model-evaluation

I have two models for estimating impact of some intervention on some metric. They take some sample as an input and return a single value.

Full sample has 170k observations, which are a representative sample from some population. I randomly sample some number of observations out of the full sample and calculate the metric using two models. I repeat it multiple times, each time getting one estimate per model. I later compare the calculated impact to the true value calculated on 170k observations.

My intentions in this are comparing the performance between the two models, as well as observing how size of input affects predictions with regards to bias and variance.

My questions are: should I sample with replacement or without replacement? Furthermore, should I compare the model output to true value calculated on 170k observations or instead only to those observations which weren’t part of the model input?

Comment: Are you looking for a [tag:prediction-interval], rather than a [tag:confidence-interval]? There is [a difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info). PIs can be evaluated using actual observations and Winkler scores, CIs are much harder to assess.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I think one of the models (bayesian stats-based) returns the former and another (bootstrap-based) the latter. Thanks for pointing it out.
I'll leave out CI/PIs from my original question for clarity. My main focus is judging the quality of the point estimates.